# Win32 API check if current window is dialog or normal window

Tags: c++, c, api, winapi

I'm dealing with win32 api subclass. My issue is I don't know my subclass procedure is running on a dialog or a "normal window". Can anyone tell me how can I determine current window is a dialog or a normal window?

Comment: Why do you need to behave differently? Dialog boxes are windows, so a solution for general windows should also work for dialogs.

Comment: I want to pass a struct's pointer to that window but if its dialog then i use `DWL_USER` in `SetWindowLong` function otherwise is `GWL_USERDATA`. And at this point i have confused that is my way is right or it can done by other ways (ex. is `GWL_USERDATA`  available in dialog)?

Comment: How do you know that `GWL_USERDATA` and `DWL_USER` are safe to use? What if the window/dialog is already using that for some other purpose?

Comment: @RaymondChen: I stored old user data and pass to window when call `CallWindowProc` and then associate my data to again. it seems complicate but it works.

Comment: `GWL_USERDATA` is also available for dialogs. Dialogs have all of the same values as regular windows (because they *are* windows), they just add the additional `DWL_Xxx` values. But like Raymond says, `GWL_USERDATA` should **only** be used by the application that created the window. You can't just go wiping out some other application's private data. Saving and trying to restore it is really not a good solution. How/when are you trying to pass this pointer? Can you send the window/dialog a message instead?

Comment: @CodyGray: I trying to create a abstract controls (including main window or dialog) by wrapper Win32 API, each controls has seperate window procedures. it makes me think that i have to subclass its WndProc, the main controls WndProc is in class, so that i have to pass class instance (in fact i pass `this` pointer :D) to window to access anything which not static data. i don't know if this can use message instead. PS: Sorry for my bad english :D

Comment: BTW: Is `GWL_WNDPROC` and `DWL_WNDPROC` return same value?

Comment: Use a window property or a private registered message that packs a MSG in the lParam and the instance data in the wParam. Don't go messing with somebody else's data. (Besides what if somebody else sends the dialog a message? Your subclass will access the DWL_USER thinking it is your private instance pointer but it's not. Result: crash-o-rama.)

Comment: @RaymondChen: Now i use `SetProp` instead of `SetWindowLong`, hope it safe :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check the name of the window class. There is no formal documented way of determining this other than that.

Comment: @BìnhNguyên: Use `RealGetWindowClass` and check that the result is the string `#32770`. [Don't use `GetClassName`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/12/31/10110524.aspx), because it won't work in some cases.

Comment: @Mehrdad: you should post your comments as answer. Maybe I should undelete my wrong answer, with the sole purpose to display your comment?

Comment: @chac: Nah, I think it's fine; thanks for the suggestion though.